# Is the column vector of a uniformly sampled random unitary matrix a uniformly sampled random state vector?

Tags: matrix-representation, unitarity, quantum-state, haar-distribution

I am wondering if a random unitary matrix taken from a Haar measure (as in, it is uniformly sampled at random) can yield a uniformly sampled random state vector.

In section 3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.03644.pdf) it says "It is worthwhile mentioning that, although not advantageous, it is possible to use the rows or columns of such a random unitary matrix as random state vector" and also says in the previous section that " Another manner of obtaining samples with similar properties is by using the rows or columns of random unitary matrices, which we shall discuss in the next section."

I am a bit confused by the wording of this paper. Is it explicitly saying that taking a column or row from a random unitary matrix sampled uniformly will in fact give a random state vector with respect to the Haar measure?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

A uniformly (Haar random) sampled state vector $|\psi\rangle$ is characterized by the fact that the probability measure is invariant under any $U$, i.e., colloquially, $U|\psi\rangle$ is just as likely as $|\psi\rangle$ for any unitary $U$.

On the other hand, a Haar random unitary $V$ is defined the same way: "$UV$ is just as likely as $V$, for any $U$."

Thus, a column of $V$, let's call is $|\chi\rangle$, has again the property that  $|\chi\rangle$ and $U|\chi\rangle$ for any $U$ are "equally likely", that is, $|\chi\rangle$ is distributed Haar random.

(As stated in the beginning, the colloquial "equally likely" should be understood as an invariance property of the measure.)

Comment: can you elaborate more on: "Thus, a column of $V$, let's call is $|\chi\rangle$, has again the property that  $|\chi\rangle$ and $U|\chi\rangle$ for any $U$ are "equally likely", that is, $|\chi\rangle$ is distributed Haar random." Why is  $|\chi\rangle$ and $U|\chi\rangle$ for any $U$  "equally likely"?

Comment: given a column vector, does that map to a unique unitary? not sure how to show that.

Comment: @QuantumGuy123 No, obviously not, just by parameter counting.

Comment: @QuantumGuy123 With regard to the first question: If the probability of picking a unitary U or V\*U are the same, then also the probability of picking their respective first columns, which are chi (for U, that's how I define chi) and U\*chi, are the same.

Comment: ok thanks. also can you provide a reference/source for the two claims you stated: 

1) A uniformly (Haar random) sampled state vector $|\psi\rangle$ is characterized by the fact that the probability measure is invariant under any $U$, i.e., colloquially, $U|\psi\rangle$ is just as likely as $|\psi\rangle$ for any unitary $U$.

and 2) On the other hand, a Haar random unitary $V$ is defined the same way: "$UV$ is just as likely as $V$, for any $U$."

Comment: the only reason I ask is because i find the definitions of Haar measures I've seen before are quite difficult to understand. your definitions are easy to understand though

Comment: an explanation of those claims would be helpful as well. thanks a bunch for the answers.

Comment: What definitions have you seen?

Answer (score 4):

Suppose that was not the case. Then taking the first column of a uniformly random unitary matrix gives you a *non*uniformly random state.

That means that there is some state, call it $|\psi\rangle$, that is relatively more likely to be found when sampling states with such procedure. But that would mean that the unitaries whose first column is $|\psi\rangle$ are relatively more likely to be found than others. This is clearly against the assumption that the unitaries are *uniformly* sampled. We conclude that taking the first (or any other) column of a uniformly sampled unitary matrix gives a uniformly sampled quantum state.

Comment: "This pretty much just boils down to observing that there is a bijection between (pure) quantum states and the k-th columns of unitary matrices." that is not true. two different  unitary matrices can have the same k-th column.

Comment: @QuantumGuy123 true, I removed that statement